# 404 error when using Jade/Pug to output audio on a webpage

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I am trying to use the IBM Watson Text to Speech api through a webpage. On the webpage I have a form that takes the sentence or word the user wants to have read and a button "SPEAK!" that finalizes and reads the form input. My issue is that when I am looking in the console to make sure everything is going smoothly I see that my audio file is not being found.

App.js -- this is the code that connects to the api and then sends the synthesized code to "audioFiles/Output.ogg" where they can be accessed.

```
var input;
app.get("/speech", function(req, res, next) {
 input = req.query.speech;
 const TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
 const fs = require('file-system');
 if(input) {
   var intentValNumber = input.length;
 }
 console.log(intentValNumber);
 if (intentValNumber > 0) {
   const text_to_speech = new TextToSpeechV1({
       url: "URL is here",
       username: 'UserName is here',
       password: 'PassWord is here',
       version_date: TextToSpeechV1.VERSION_DATE_2017_04_26
     });
     var params = {
       text: input,
       voice: 'en-US_MichaelVoice',
       accept: 'audio/ogg'
     };
     console.log(input);
  // Pipe the synthesized text to a file.
   text_to_speech.synthesize(params).on('error', function(error) {
     console.log('Error:', error);
   }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('audioFiles/output.ogg'));
 };
next();
});
```

speech.pug -- this is where the form and the audio should be performed.

```
extends layout

block content
 .main.container.row
  .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
    h1.display-4.m-b-2 Magic Reading!
     form(method="GET" action="/speech")
      div.form-group
       label(for='speech') Type something to be spoken:
       input#speech.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Type something to be read' name='speech')
       button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') SPEAK!
       audio(controls='', autoplay='')
         source(src='../audioFiles/output.ogg', type='audio/ogg')
```

Specific error - GET http://localhost:3000/audioFiles/output.ogg

Thanks in advance for any advice! Also let me know if anyone needs more information about the error or code.

EDIT -- this is a simplified version of my directory structure...

```
 Project
  |
  +-- audioFiles(folder)
  |   |
  |   + - output.ogg
  |   + - music.mp3
  |
  +-- public(folder)
  |     |
  |     + - images(folder)
  |     + - stylesheets(folder)
  |    
  +-- routes(folder)
  |    |  
  |    +-- index.js
  |    
  +-- views(folder)
  |    |  
  |    +-- speech.pug
  |    
  + -- app.js
```

Comment: Does `audioFiles/output.ogg` exist on server ? If yes, then you have problem loading static content.

Comment: @Mukesh Sharma Yes, it does exist on the server. If I have an issue loading static content, how would I fix that?

Comment: cool. Show your directory structure. You have to use `express.static`

Comment: @Mukesh Sharma I added an edit to my main post with the directory structure.

Comment: I was just reading about static files and it said that a static file is a file that does not change depending on user input or actions but, my audio file changes depending on the form input given. Would that still be a static file or do I have another issue rather than an error loading static files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in your `app.js`

`app.use("/audioFiles", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "audioFiles")))`

Then, http://localhost:3000/audioFiles/output.ogg shouldn't give `404` error.

Comment: Great thanks! It does get rid of the 404 error and it is emitting the audio on the page! Just one more question and this may completely lead you in the other direction... Can static files update "on the fly" or in real time? I mentioned, somewhere in my most recent comment/reply that my audio file needed to change when input changed. Would static files have ability to change like this? Sorry if this completely changes the question I was originally asking.

Comment: `static` is vague term. Yes, if underlying files change, url will serve latest content.

Comment: I have been trying the code you have given me and it works great, just one issue. When my audio file changes, the site is not serving the new audio, it is serving the previous audio file. I notice that it only changes when I leave the site and come back. I need it to change as soon as the audio file changes. How can I do this? Part of me believes that I need some other technique other than the "express.static" approach...